# _interopRequireDefault is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a react app in code sandbox but keep getting:

TypeError:
_interopRequireDefault is not a function
as soon as I type

`import React from "react"`

How do I fix it.
Adding @babel/runtime to dependencies is not helping.

Comment: You are getting that error in a codesandbox? [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the problem in Codesandbox.

Comment: Can you share link of your sandbox if it is a public?